# iFrame and matching sidebar div height

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a html page. I have an iframe in it, that resizes when the content is loaded in it, but i have a sidebar(div) that I need to set height equal to new iframe height.
My javascript for iframe resize is

```
function setIframeHeight( iframeId ) /** IMPORTANT: All framed documents *must* have a               DOCTYPE applied **/  
{
 var ifDoc, ifRef = document.getElementById( iframeId );

 try
 {   
  ifDoc = ifRef.contentWindow.document.documentElement;  
 }
 catch( e )
 { 
  try
  { 
    ifDoc = ifRef.contentDocument.documentElement;  
   }
  catch(ee)
  {   
  }  
 }

 if( ifDoc )
 {
  ifRef.height = 1;  
   ifRef.height = ifDoc.scrollHeight;

  /* For width resize, enable below.  */

  // ifRef.width = 1;
  // ifRef.width = ifDoc.scrollWidth; 
 }
}
```

Actualy the code is not mine, Credits to Logic Ali .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have an onResize handler like such.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

```
window.onresize=function(){
    setIframeHeight( iframeId )
};
```

Comment: Im not a very good javascripter, so I would apriciate if you told me a bit more what to do with this, thank you :)